# MongoDB: working with relational schema

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and would appreciate any suggestion I can get here. We have recently changed the data storage from MySQL to MongoDB but we didn't change the schema. Now we store data as follow: each document in collection has data from all tables for a given entry. Each table now a field in document with rows stored in array. All operations that were fast and easy in SQL are very slow now and require to write customer code.

My current issue is how to implement SQL join for fields (tables before). An example:

```
{
  table1:[{id: 1, prop1: a}, {id: 2, prop1: b}],
  table2:[{id: 1, prop2: c}]
  table3:[{id: 2, prop3: d}]
}
```

I need to get list of objects merged as follow:

```
[ 
  {id: 1, prop1: a, prop2:c},
  {id: 2, prop1: b, prop3:d}
]
```

Could you recommend how to best achieve this transformation? Thank you!

Comment: try $lookup on table2 and table3 from table1

Answer (score 1):

Perform aggregation with $lookup on tables. 
e.g.

`db.table1.aggregate([
     {
        $lookup:{
             from: "table2",
             localField: "id",
             foreignField: "id",
             as: "table2"
        }
     }
   ])`

It will return output as 

  `{id: 1, prop1: a, table2: [{id: 1, prop2: c}]}`

for better understanding follow https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. In my case "table1" and "table2" are the fields of the same document within same collection so I cannot use $lookup operator.

Comment: IMO, if table1 and table2 are  documents, then you have to pull the data from the collections and then have to apply filter on it.